# Having trouble getting the maximum value from a log ratio matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to normalize a matrix of log ratio, so in order to do that, I want to find the maximum of the matrix. But I got infinite which is kind of impossible.

The code I've wrote:

```py
import imageio as im
import numpy as np

imagepath1 = 'Andasol_09051987.jpg'
imagepath2 = 'Andasol_09122013.jpg'
image1 = im.imread(imagepath1)
image2 = im.imread(imagepath2)

Ds = np.abs(image1 - image2)
Dl = np.abs(np.log(image2+1)-np.log(image1+1))

Dsmax = Ds.max()
Dsmin = Ds.min()
Ds = ((Ds - Dsmax)/(Dsmax - Dsmin))*255

Dlmax = np.amax(Dl)
Dlmin = Dl.min()
Dl = ((Dl - Dlmax)/(Dlmax - Dlmin))*255
```

For the subtraction Ds part, things working well, but Dl part does not work.  The value of Dlmax is infinite.

And for the calculation of the log ratio

```py
Dl = np.abs(np.log(image2+1)-np.log(image1+1))
```

It has a warning RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  Dl = np.abs(np.log(image2+1)-np.log(image1+1))

I really want to avoid divided by 0 that's why I add 1 to every pixel.

Both images are grayscale, so the value of each pixel varies from [0 255]